# How do you allocate a movie clip to the center of a editable stage at the button command?

Tags: actionscript-3

In ActionScript I am try to use a button to generate an editable stage and allocate a movie clip to the center of the new stage.

This is my first set of goals and my attempts aren't working and I figured I'd ask for help:

1. Use the first movie clip as an orientation point (0) in an array
2. Populate it with clones of the first movie clip in Compass directions via a numeric stepper.

Comment: Unclear. What is "editable stage"?

Comment: editable stage: I want to increase the stage size in respect to the number of clones denoted from the numeric stepper. one stepper for each (x and y, which will go in both pos and neg directions).

Comment: Stage dimensions are read-only (from inside) in most cases (defined by HTML element in browser or screen resolution in mobile apps), unless you're talking about Desktop AIR application. Are you talking about Desktop AIR?

Comment: I am making a Android Air application.

Comment: Then you cannot change stage width and height, they are determined by resolution of the device the app is running on.

Comment: oh... didn't know that, thanks I will need to set a max

Answer (score 0):

Normally to keep track of stage dimensions you put this into the root document class:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        public var Central:Sprite;

        public function Main() 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
            stage.showDefaultContextMenu = false;
            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.stageFocusRect = false;
            stage.color = 0x00000000;

            stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, onResize);
        }

        private function onResize(event:Event = null):void
        {
            // Handle new stage dimensions here by
            // stage.stageWidth
            // stage.stageHeight

            Central.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            Central.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
        }
    }
}
```

The center of the stage is (stage.stageWidth / 2, stage.stageHeight / 2). Then if you have content that exceeds stage width and height you scale it down by .scaleX and .scaleY properties.

Comment: thanks just saw this... diving the stage height makes a lot of sense

Comment: I need to try this out.. thank you and how do you plug in the numeric counter?

Comment: Depends on IDE you are working with. In Flash IDE it is probably menu > Window > Components.

Comment: Forgive me I am an artist and just started with actionscript, I meant in the script... what function do I plug it into?

Comment: I've updated the example. If you place an object with instance name "Central" on your main timeline then it will cling to center of your stage. I advise you to find someone with a knowledge of AS3 and Android to collaborate with, unless you're building something overly simple.